# How to stop a running docker container 'X' minutes from startup?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, podman

I would like to stop my running docker container after a specific time, let's say 2 hrs after startup. So far my research has led to the following solutions. I just wanted to know if there were better ways to do it.

1. Use a cron job to stop the container by calling the docker stop command.
2. Use an entry point like sleep 5000, but this does not suit my use case.
3. Using `--stop-timeout` in the docker run command ; I believe this is just the maximum timeout given for the container to gracefully shutdown. Am I missing something
   here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `timeout` command that's part of the coreutils package which is already installed in the debian images (and probably many others).

This will run the container for 30 seconds and then stop

```
docker run debian timeout 30 tail -f /dev/null
```

Basically, add `timeout 7200` in front of the command you want to run in the container, and it'll be killed after 2 hours.